# How to connect to Ubuntu via VNC from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I need to connect to Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows with VNC; I followed [this tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-establish-simple-remote-desktop-access-between-ubuntu-and-windows/) and I tried both with *UltraVNC Viewer* and *TightVNC Viewer*, but in both cases after inserting the password I only obtain a grey screen...it looks like I am connected, but I can't see anything.
[image: Grey screen]

 Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see that there is a connection in the logs on the host machine but get no image. How did you solve it?

Comment: @EdgarH  I did not resolve it...I decided that TeamViewer is perfect for my needs so I switched to it

Answer (score 0):

When you start `vncserver` try this:

```
vncserver -localhost no
```